# How to use vue-resource with a vue-router instance?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource, vue-router, vue-component

Before I installed my router I set up a global Vue instance and used vue-resource like this:

```
export const befriend = (recipient, event) => {
    Vue.http.post('/route',{
        // Data
    }).then(function(response) {
        // Success
    }.bind(this), function(response) {
        // Error
    });
}
```

Now my Vue instance is being instantiated by the router itself like this:

```
router.start(App, 'body');
```

How can I use vue-resource when I have no variable bound to my instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I found the answer in the vue-router documentation hidden at the bottom of the page.

> In addition:
>
> The root Vue instance will be available as router.app once the initial
>   render is complete.
>
> The router instance will be available in all descendants of the router
>   app as this.$router.

Hope this is of use for someone else who didn't read every bit of the docu mentation.